# Display code flow on UI in java web application

Tags: java, ajax, spring, real-time, reverse-ajax

I have a java web application, developed in Spring Framework. In that, I am running a job (like moving data from one database to other database).

I want to track the progress of the operation, not by displaying some progress bar, instead of that, I want to display the real time logs, to track the flow, on the UI.

I was using reverse AJAX using DWR but it seems, excessive use of it, is creating outofmemory error.

How can I achieve it?

**web.xml Code**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrSpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>activeReverseAjaxEnabled</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Ajax file code**

```
@RemoteMethod
    public void moveData() {
        String currentPage = WebContextFactory.get().getCurrentPage();

        Browser.withPage(currentPage, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DatabaseUtility.moveDB();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you share your dwr servlet code?

Comment: updated...Inside moveDB()..I am using `Util.setValue("status", "Checking Server Status");` ..... to update the content in the UI